# Delete a whole page using PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I am using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to edit Word documents. How can I use it to delete an entire page from a document?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete a page using PHPWord.

In an other way, you can delimit a page by a bloc tag ${YOUR_BLOC} ... ${/YOUR_BLOC} and delete the bloc content.

Comment: Delete block will work but it its content will remain blank page

Answer (score 1):

An alternative hack is to set the section height to 0

```
$section->setStyle(['pageSizeH' => 0]);
```

This is a hack, so might have some rendering issues in some version.